# Locking down chrome extension permissions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to lock down Chrome for my users.  I know you can whitelist extensions, force installation of others and prevent all other extensions from installing. I've done this, and it works well. Except for one hitch.

For those extensions I force install, I want the extensions to have the necessary permissions. But my users can go into the extension details and the site access section, change "Allow this extension to read and change all your data on websites you visit" to on click or a specific site instead of all sites. It effectively makes some extensions useless. Can I lock down that configuration via policies? I couldn't find anything for that.

Comment: Try listing those sites in `runtime_allowed_hosts`.

Comment: Wow. That looks hopeful, w0xx0m.  Thank you.  It looks like runtime_allowed_hosts takes an array of strings.  Any idea how to specify this in the Windows Registry?  If not, I'll figure it out eventually, I imagine

Comment: It's a JSON like `{"id":{"runtime_allowed_hosts":["pattern1", "pattern1"]}}` in `ExtensionSettings` value under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome key.

Comment: Thanks w0xx0m.  That's awesome, for later user.  My problem, it turned out, was a little different.  I had installed an extension not using the policies.  Later, I applied policies. For that extension that was manually installed, instead of force installed, some properties were not locked down.  The workaround was to remove force install, remove extension entirely, then install it through force install. Doing it this way locked down all the properties on the extension.